# I am building an extension using manifest v3 with the config below, I am unable to view/open my popup when dev tools is open

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3, browser-extension

```
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "chrome-extension-svelte-typescript-boilerplate",
  "description": "Boilerplate for Chrome Extension Svelte Typescript project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "version_name": "1.0.0",
  "icons": {
    "16": "src/assets/icons/icon-16.png",
    "32": "src/assets/icons/icon-32.png",
    "48": "src/assets/icons/icon-48.png",
    "128": "src/assets/icons/icon-128.png"
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "js": [
        "assets/index.ts-loader-1e2bd80e.js"
      ],
      "matches": [
        "https://*/*"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "service-worker-loader.js",
    "type": "module"
  },
  "options_ui": {
    "page": "src/options/options.html",
    "open_in_tab": true
  },
  "side_panel": {
    "default_path": "src/sidepanel/sidepanel.html"
  },
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "src/popup/popup.html",
    "default_icon": {
      "16": "src/assets/icons/icon-16.png",
      "32": "src/assets/icons/icon-32.png",
      "48": "src/assets/icons/icon-48.png",
      "128": "src/assets/icons/icon-128.png"
    }
  },
  "permissions": [
    "storage",
    "sidePanel",
    "tabs",
    "activeTab",
    "webNavigation",
    "webRequest",
    "notifications"
  ],
  "web_accessible_resources": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "https://*/*"
      ],
      "resources": [
        "assets/api-c5a78f60.js",
        "assets/index.ts-d1f6ef4e.js"
      ],
      "use_dynamic_url": true
    }
  ]
}
```

Should anything modified in the config to make the popup visible even when devtools is open or is it something we need to handle in the extension scripts?

I tried to see if any additional configurations are present for popup in manifest v3 but couldn't find any

Comment: Sounds like a bug in Chrome or maybe you added a breakpoint in the Sources panel in devtools.

Comment: Actually while debugging I noticed something strange, I was able to open the popup when there was not any background service worker registered in the manifest v3.

Comment: Certainly sounds like a bug, you can report it in https://crbug.com. There's also a possibility your service-worker-loader.js is causing this bug due to an error in the code so it fails during registration.